# chatbot that will generate a document draft with python, langchain, and openai

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, llama-index

I'm attempted to pass draft documents and have my chatbot generate a template using a prompt `create a non disclosure agreement draft for California between mike llc and fantasty world.` with my code below the response i'm getting is:
`"I'm sorry, but I cannot generate a non-disclosure agreement draft for you. However, you can use the provided context information as a template to create a non-disclosure agreement between Mike LLC and fantasty world. Just replace the placeholders in the template with the appropriate names and information for your specific agreement.`

Here is my setup:

```
import sys
import os
import openai
import constants
import gradio as gr
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTListIndex, GPTVectorStoreIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper, load_index_from_storage

# Disable SSL certificate verification (for debugging purposes)
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''  # Set it to an empty string

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = constants.APIKEY
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
print(os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"))

def createVecorIndex(path):
    max_input = 4096
    tokens = 512
    chunk_size = 600
    max_chunk_overlap = 0.1

    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input, tokens, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size)

    #define llm
    llmPredictor = LLMPredictor(llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=.7, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo', max_tokens=tokens))

    #load data
    docs = SimpleDirectoryReader(path).load_data()

    #create vector index
    vectorIndex = GPTVectorStoreIndex(docs, llmpredictor=llmPredictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper)
    vectorIndex.storage_context.persist(persist_dir='vectorIndex.json')

    return vectorIndex

vectorIndex = createVecorIndex('docs')
```

In my docs directory, I have a few examples of non-disclosure agreements to create the vector index.

This was my first attempt at the query:

```
def chatbot(input_index):
    query_engine = vectorIndex.as_query_engine()
    response = query_engine.query(input_index)
    return response.response

gr.Interface(fn=chatbot, inputs="text", outputs="text", title="Super Awesome Chatbot").launch()
```

I can't seem to get it to generate the draft, it keeps giving me the "I cannot generate a draft" response

I also tried to create a clause for the word draft, but the setup below is essential useing the trained model instead my vector.

```
def chatbot(input_index):
    query_engine = vectorIndex.as_query_engine()

    # If the "draft" clause is active:
    if "draft" in input_index.lower():
        # Query the vectorIndex for relevant information/context
        vector_response = query_engine.query(input_index).response
        print(vector_response)
        # Use vector_response as context to query the OpenAI API for a draft
        prompt = f"Based on the information: '{vector_response}', generate a draft for the input: {input_index}"
        
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-002",
            prompt=prompt,
            max_tokens=512,
            temperature=0.2
        )
        
        openai_response = response.choices[0].text.strip()
        
        return openai_response

    # If "draft" clause isn't active, use just the vectorIndex response
    else:
        print('else clause')
        return query_engine.query(input_index).response
```

Comment: If I paste that prompt into `gpt-3.5-turbo` or `text-davinci-002`, it attempts to generate a non-disclosure agreement. It's not clear why your code has a poor quality text completion model in the `chatbot` function, even though `gpt-3.5-turbo` is used earlier and is actually designed for actual chatbot use. It seems like your `vector_response` is entirely the issue; but without seeing what the actual string it, or having any kind of [mre], I'm not sure how much we can help.

Comment: This is a problem with your trained model.  I'm not sure what you expect us to help you with other than "fix your model or get one that works"

Comment: @RandomDavis I don’t follow, what do you mean by poor quality text model?

Comment: @possum any advice on how to train it better? I’m new to this and thought the vector creation was the training part…like I mentioned I have template documents in the docs directory. I’m guessing training better means giving more examples?

Comment: This is not the right venue to ask those questions.

Comment: @MikeMann I meant `text-davinci-002`; it's not clear why you chose that model but maybe I just don't understand vector queries. But it just seems like you're passing a prompt straight to the `Completion` API, not using a special version of that language model. So it's just not clear why you would choose to use the deprecated Completion API or that deprecated LLM.

Comment: @RandomDavis oh I understand, even with the davinci model I get some sort of draft. But I think it’s because that clause is passing the attempted directly to the completion like you said. I guess I’ll have to troubleshoot the vector index some more

Comment: @RandomDavis i figured it out actually. it was because i was using `as_query_engine()` instead of `as_chat_engine()` the query engine seems to be for simple queries only. Thanks for your help

Comment: @possum a suggestion for you...if you're unable to assist or if the question doesn't align with your expertise, it might be best to skip it. Let's keep this community supportive and welcoming for everyone.

Comment: Was (most of) the code itself generated by ChatGPT (or similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
import os
import openai
import constants
import gradio as gr
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTListIndex, GPTVectorStoreIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper, load_index_from_storage

# Disable SSL certificate verification (for debugging purposes)
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''  # Set it to an empty string

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = constants.APIKEY
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

def createVecorIndex(path):
    max_input = 4096
    tokens = 512
    chunk_size = 600
    max_chunk_overlap = 0.1

    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input, tokens, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size)

    #define llm
    llmPredictor = LLMPredictor(llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.3, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo', max_tokens=tokens))

    #load data
    docs = SimpleDirectoryReader(path).load_data()

    #create vector index
    vectorIndex = GPTVectorStoreIndex(docs, llmpredictor=llmPredictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper)
    vectorIndex.storage_context.persist(persist_dir='vectorIndex.json')

    return vectorIndex

vectorIndex = createVecorIndex('docs')

def chatbot(input_index):
    # query_engine = vectorIndex.as_query_engine() simple query engine only
    query_engine = vectorIndex.as_chat_engine()
    response = query_engine.query(input_index)
    return response.response

gr.Interface(fn=chatbot, inputs="text", outputs="text", title="Super Awesome Chatbot").launch()
```

I updated the engine to `as_chat_engine()` instead of `as_query_engine()` and now I'm getting more complex responses